# Asynchronous behavior of CUDA events within a CUDA stream

Tags: cuda, cuda-streams, cuda-events

This question is about notion of a CUDA stream (Stream) and the apparent anomaly with CUDA events (Event) recorded on a stream.

Consider the following code demonstrating this anamoly,

```
cudaEventRecord(eventStart, stream1)
kernel1<<<..., stream1>>>(...)
cudaEventRecord(eventBetween, stream1)
kernel2<<<..., stream1>>>(...)
cudaEventRecord(eventEnd, stream1)
```

Since all work on a Stream is sequential, the following sequence of events should've happened,

1. "`eventStart`" is recorded to be complete
2. `kernel1` runs and completes
3. "`eventBetween`" is recorded to have completed
4. `kernel2` runs and completes
5. "`eventEnd`" is recorded to have completed

After synchronizing the host thread with the device, the time taken between `eventStart` and `eventBetween` ( measured by `cudaEventElapsedTime` ) should be run-time of `kernel1` and the time taken between `eventBetween` and `eventEnd` should be run-time of `kernel2`.

But according to [NVIDIA's documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1gc301fd024e6fd4a17074d229d4504077) on `cudaStreamWaitEvent`,

> Makes all future work submitted to stream wait until event reports
>   completion before beginning execution.

and [blogpost](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-overlap-data-transfers-cuda-cc/),

> You can also synchronize operations within a single stream on a
>   specific event using cudaStreamWaitEvent(event)

Events needn't report completion before all work that's scheduled after recording the Event on the same Stream. This comes as a surprise since all work scheduled on a Stream is supposed to run in a sequential fashion.

Can someone clarify this asynchronous behavior of Events within a Stream ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the cause of your confusion is conflating host-stream synchronisation and stream-stream synchronisation.

In short:

1. Streams are FIFO, and all operations within a stream are synchronous with respect to one another.
2. The documentation you are referring to is describing a use case where the programmer wishes to synchronise between events in different streams.
3. The blog post you refer to is discussing synchronisation between the calling *host thread* and an event enqueued in a stream. There are three levels of host-device synchronisation granularity available -- the whole device, a whole stream, or an event within a stream. The blog is describing the latter.

There is no contradiction between any of the sources you cited.